# CSR algorithm/size incorrect. Expected: RSA(2048) in Stripe for ApplePay

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, stripe-payments, applepay

The CSR file downloaded from stripe, when I upload it for merchant ID, it says CSR algorithm/size incorrect. Expected: RSA(2048).

Comment: See this answer on a related question with the same error: https://stackoverflow.com/a/71117146/670028

Answer (score 2):

this is a good question for Stripe support to help with![1]

Usually this means the merchant ID you're using on your Apple Developer account has been used to generate a payment certificate for China. Try creating a new merchant ID or deleting the one you've created and try again.

[1] https://support.stripe.com/email/login

Answer (score 0):

I'm using Authorize.net, not Stripe, but had the exact same error message when I uploaded Authorize.net's CSR.

I had previously created a CSR on my Mac and used that to create a certificate in my Apple developer account. After revoking that certificate, I was then able to upload the new Authorize.net CSR and it was successful.

Thus, for me this error was more about something happening on the Apple side than about Authorize.net's CSR [or Stripe's, for the OP].