# Apple Merchant Identity Cert not accepting ECC 256 Certificate Signing Request (CSR)?

Tags: ios, certificate, applepay, apple-developer, apple-developer-account

When trying to create a CSR for a Merchant Identity Certificate in Apple Pay Dev console i get the following error:

```
CSR algorithm/size incorrect. Expected: RSA(2048)
```

This used to accept an ECC 256 CSR - has that changed?

Comment: did you found the caused error ?

Answer (score 0):

The Certificate Signing Request for the Merchant Identity Certificate requires the RSA-2048 algorithm. You can use openSSL to generate the CSR via the following steps:

1. Execute the following openSSL command to create a private key:

`openssl genrsa -out privateKey.key 2048`

2. Execute the following openSSL command to generate a certificate signing request (CSR) from the private key:

`openssl req -new -key privateKey.key -out certificateSigningRequest.csr`

3. Login to the Apple Developer Portal and upload the CSR file. You can then download the newly generated certifiate.

Comment: But it should also accept ECC 256 CSR.

I generate this private key:
`openssl ecparam -out apple_pay_private.key -name prime256v1 -genkey`

Then i generate CSR:
`openssl req -new -sha256 -key apple_pay_private.key -nodes -out apple_pay_request.csr `
Input all details for CSR request

Then i upload the CSR to Apple and got the error:  Expected: RSA(2048).

Do you know why it happens?

Comment: @master17, the industry standards, set by the Certification Authority/Browser (CA/B) Forum, state that certificates issued after January 1, 2014 must be at least 2048 bits. See [Baseline Requirements for the Issuance and Management of Publicly-Trusted Certificates](https://cabforum.org/baseline-requirements-documents/)

Comment: @master17, also per Apple documentation, *"You can create RSA keys up to 4096 bits. RSA keys smaller than 2048 bits are no longer supported."* See: [Create self-signed certificates in Keychain Access on Mac](https://support.apple.com/guide/keychain-access/create-self-signed-certificates-kyca8916/11.0/mac/11.0) and [Requirements for trusted certificates in iOS 13 and macOS 10.15](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT210176)

Comment: thanks for your reply. These requirements are applied to RSA keys. But i want to create ECC 256 keys encrypted. Also, i wrote application in my company that helps our customers to CREATE CSR on our side with ECC256 encryption three years ago. And everything works. But now, just wanted to create via openssl command and uploaded to Apple site, saw this error.  Also, 256 key length of ECC equivalent to 3072 length of RSA key. And i indicate in openssl command that the keys are ECC type. I don't understand why it's not workin.

Comment: @master17, I've created an [Updating Apple Pay Certificates](https://gist.github.com/randyburden/bac588ed3017a6eadf858523e9917d0d) document that outlines all the steps to update both an Apple Pay Payment Processing Certificate and an Apple Pay Merchant Identity Certificate using OpenSSL commands. Based on your last comment, ECC 256 is required to create the CSR for the Apple Pay Payment Processing Certificate, but RSA 2048 is required to create the CSR for the Apple Pay Merchant Identity Certificate.